# Trigger workflow when pull request is raised

Tags: github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions to build the maven project. The action is triggered whenever the pull request is pushed to `dev` branch. But the action is NOT triggered when the pull request is raised against the `dev` branch.

Following is the workflow on the `dev` branch:

```
name: Backend Maven CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  sigma-backend-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_ECR_REPO_URL: 
      JOB_URL: ${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id  }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: "11"
          distribution: "temurin"
          cache: maven

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
```

How to resolve the issue? To trigger the workflow when pull request is raised